# Php unlink() dont delete a image file

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**want to delete a procuct and delete the image of the product but don't no what is missing.
The product are deleting fine but don't delete the image**

```
if((isset($_GET["remove"])) && ($_GET["remove"] != "")){

    $idproduct = $_GET["remove"];

    $sql ="DELETE FROM product WHERE idproduct = '".$idproduct."'";
    if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die ("Erro")){

    //the part that don't work 
    $file = $frontpage_url."/images/".$_FILES["imagem"]["name"]; unlink($file);

    echo "success";

    }
}
```

Comment: what is `$frontpage_url` ?

Comment: try putting the unlink file before your sql code

Comment: @user3010773: why should that matter? don't *try*. this is programming, not voodoo.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath If he is calling for the file with mysql and he deletes the data of the file then `unlink` will fail

Comment: @user3010773: I have no idea what you're talking about. mysql records and filesystem are completely independent things.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Alright lets say he as the name of his file stored in a record on MySQL, if he deletes the row with his file information, he deleted the name of his file. So if he were to call for that name in the `unlink` function. It would fail because the name is blank.

Comment: @user3010773 you are getting the wrong idea, he is using `$_FILES["imagem"]["name"];` to get the name of the file he wants to unlink. Not from the `filename` on the database.

Answer (score 2):

Check the unlink [docs](http://www.php.net/unlink).

The `unlink` requires the parameter to be a path to the file on your local filesystem.

From the looks of `$frontpage_url` you are giving it an url to the image which is not supported by `unlink` and also makes no sense on why that should work.

Example:

```
unlink('/home/path/to/image.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
unlink("images/".$_FILES["imagem"]["name"]);
```

If still not working, append your full path to the "images/" folder. E.g.:

```
unlink("public/uploads/images/".$_FILES["imagem"]["name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$file = "images/".$_FILES["imagem"]["name"];
unlink($file);
```